# Losing unsaved changes in original branch when checking out new branch and then running "git reset --hard"

Tags: git, github

Had a recent issue with losing a bunch of unsaved code changes on a shared machine and I'm trying to understand exactly what went wrong as it's made me realize there are still some things about git I don't fully understand. What happened was:

1) Dev1 has a bunch of unstaged changes in the master branch

2) Dev2 logs on and wants to test merge another feature branch with master. He runs `git branch` and sees he is already in the master branch. The runs `git checkout -b test && git fetch origin && git merge origin/feature` and builds the app. Done testing, he then rolls back the merge on the test branch using `git reset --hard HEAD~1` before switching back master using `git checkout master`.

3) Dev1 logs back on and finds that he has lost all his unstaged changes in the local master branch

I realize this is something to do with running `git reset --hard HEAD~1` in the test branch but I can't work out why git never raised a local files overwrite error at any point.

Can someone break it down for me?

Edit: for anyone who is irritated by the notion that someone would use git without understanding it, don't worry - neither of them is me. I just witnessed the fallout and was interested to know how it happened.

Comment: Two developers should not be sharing the same working directory in the first place.

Comment: @chepner 100% agreed, I'm just curious as to how this happened

Comment: When you say shared machine, are you saying they are in different workspaces (e.g. /home/user1, /home/user2) or are they sharing the same working directory?

Comment: Have you read what `--hard` does? "Resets the index and working tree. **Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.**"

Comment: @cmbuckley same working directory. Although technically Dev2 was only temporarily 'borrowing' Dev1's machine to test the feature merge

Comment: @tofd I'm not sure it's fair, but I think your question has gotten downvotes because there is a belief you are using git without understanding it, not to mention that you are implicitly complaining that git did not warn Dev2 about overwriting work when Dev2 **explicitly* forced it too (that's what `--hard` means. If fingers must be pointed, it should be at Dev2, not git. You don't happen to be Dev2, do you? ;)

Comment: @Inigio to clarifiy, neither Dev1 or Dev2 is me, I'm new to git. I'm just trying to learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Dev1 has a bunch of unstaged changes in the master branch

No. Unstaged changes are not in any branch. They are in the worktree.

> 2) Dev2 ... runs git checkout -b test

And this was permitted because the unstaged changes in the worktree would not be overwritten by the checkout of the branch. They are still in the worktree.

> then rolls back the merge on the test branch using git reset --hard HEAD~1

Thereby replacing the worktree, in its entirety, with the exact contents of `HEAD~1`. The unstaged changes are now gone.

> 3) Dev1 logs back on and finds that he has lost all his unstaged changes in the local master branch

Because they were never in the master branch. They were *unstaged*. They were in the worktree, which is what got replaced.

If it sounds like I think you don't know what "unstaged" means, you're right. You need to learn about the most basic fact of the git, the Three Places: the repo, the stage/index, and the worktree. When you do, you'll understand perfectly because your intuitions will be mended.

Comment: thanks, that helps. I guess I was thinking that after ```git checkout -b test``` that that new test branch would have a COPY of the working tree and that if you run ```git reset --hard``` in that branch and try to ```git checkout master``` it would raise an local overwrite error because the working trees wouldn't match. But yes, fundamental misunderstanding on my part

Comment: @matt git does warn about overwriting unsaved changes all the time! But `--hard` is an explicit command to override the warning, so yet another warning seems a little silly to me.